# Rails 6, js.erb files not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing on a blog tutorial from youtube and it was working really well until I get to the part where he has an update.js.erb file that is supposed to load when updating an element on the past.  When I edit the element and click save, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (Authors::ElementsController#update is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []):
  
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:42:in `default_render'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:228:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (6.1.3) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:20:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (6.1.3) lib/action_text/engine.rb:55:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:137:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:203:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:249:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:165:in `process'
actionview (6.1.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:842:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
activerecord (6.1.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:601:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.1.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:98:in `call'
webpacker (5.2.1) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
puma (5.2.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:247:in `call'
puma (5.2.1) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.2.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:337:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.2.1) lib/puma/request.rb:75:in `handle_request'
puma (5.2.1) lib/puma/server.rb:431:in `process_client'
puma (5.2.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:145:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

The edit.html.erb file is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path, class: 'btn btn-dark mb-3' %>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h6 class='card-title mb-0'>Editing Post</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <%= render 'form', post: @post %>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <% if @post.published? %>
          <a href="#"
            class='btn btn-secondary btn-block'
            data-reflex='click->PublisherReflex#unpublish'
            data-post-id='<%= @post.id %>'>
            Unpublish
          </a>
        <% else %>
          <a href="#"
            class='btn btn-dark btn-block'
            data-reflex='click->PublisherReflex#publish'
            data-post-id='<%= @post.id %>'>
            Publish
          </a>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="mb-3">
      <%= form_with(model: [@post, @element], html: { class: 'float-left mr-1' }) do |form| %>
        <%= form.hidden_field :element_type, value: 'paragraph' %>
        <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-secondary') do %>
          <i class="fas fa-paragraph"></i>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <%= form_with(model: [@post, @element]) do |form| %>
        <%= form.hidden_field :element_type, value: 'image' %>
        <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-secondary') do %>
          <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-5">
      <div class="card-header text-right">
        <% if @post.published? %>
          <b>Published</b> <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.published_at) %> ago
        <% else %>
          Unpublished
        <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body pt-5" data-controller="elements">
        <% if @post.elements.none? { |element| element.persisted? } %>
          <div class="p-4 text-center">
            <h2 class='text-secondary'>
              <i class="fas fa-lightbulb"></i>
            </h2>
            <p>Click the icons above to add elements to this post.</p>
          </div>
        <% else %>
          <ul id='elements' data-action="drop->elements#sort">
            <% @post.elements.order(position: :asc).each do |element| %>
              <% if element.persisted? %>
                <li data-id="<%= element.id %>" class='element-item'>
                  <% if element.paragraph? %>
                    <div class="mb-4 p-3 paragraph">
                      <div class="paragraph-content">
                        <% if element.content.present? %>
                          <%= element.content %>
                        <% else %>
                          Click to add content.
                        <% end %>
                      </div>
                      <div class="paragraph-form d-none" id='element-<%= element.id %>-form'>
                        <%= form_with(model: [@post, element]) do |form| %>
                          <%= form.rich_text_area :content, id: "element_content_#{element.id}" %>
                          <div class="mt-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
                            <div>
                              <%= form.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                              <a href="#" class='cancel btn btn-secondary'>Cancel</a>
                            </div>
                            <%= link_to 'Delete', post_element_path(@post, element), method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
                          </div>
                        <% end %>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <% elsif element.image? %>
                    <div class="mb-4 p-3 image">
                      <% if element.image.present? %>
                        <%= link_to post_element_path(@post, element), method: :delete, class: 'delete-btn btn btn-dark mt-2 float-right', data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
                          <i class='fas fa-times'></i>
                        <% end %>
                        <%= image_tag(element.image) %>
                      <% else %>
                        <%= form_with(model: [@post, element]) do |form| %>
                          <%= form.file_field :image %>
                          <div class="mt-3">
                            <%= form.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
                            <a href="#" class='cancel btn btn-secondary'>Cancel</a>
                          </div>
                        <% end %>
                      <% end %>
                    </div>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The update.js.erb file is:

```
var element = document.getElementById('element-<%= @element.id %>-form')

element.classList.add('d-none')
element.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('d-none')

var html = "<div class='trix-content'><%= @element.content.body.html_safe %></div>"

element.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = html
```

And the elements controller:

```
module Authors
  class ElementsController < AuthorsController
    before_action :set_post
    before_action :set_element, only: [:update, :destroy]

    # POST /elements
    def create
      @element = @post.elements.build(element_params)

      if @element.save
        notice = nil
      else
        notice = @element.errors.full_messages.join(". ") << "."
      end
      redirect_to edit_post_path(@post), notice: notice
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /elements/1
    def update
      @element.update(element_params)
    end

    # DELETE /elements/1
    def destroy
      @element.destroy
      redirect_to edit_post_path(@element.post)
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def set_post
      @post = current_author.posts.find(params[:post_id])
    end

    def set_element
      @element = @post.elements.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def element_params
      params.require(:element).permit(:element_type, :content, :image)
    end
  end
end
```

The link to the part of the tutorial I'm following in case you want to see it is:
[Rails Tutorial | Building a Blog with Ruby on Rails 6 - Part 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCJmF6ma-6w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enable XHR form submissions, you have to pass `local: false`.

```
<%= form_with(model: [@post, @element], local: false) do |form| %>
  <%#= ... %>
<% end %>
```

This should generate a `form` tag with `data-remote` set to `true`.

From the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with),

> `:local` - By default form submits via typical HTTP requests. Enable remote and unobtrusive XHRs submits with `local: false`. Remote forms may be enabled by default by setting `config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = true`.

I would recommend using [Turbo](https://turbo.hotwire.dev) instead of the `js.erb` approach.

Comment: That did it.  In his video he added local: true and then took it out but never added local: false.  Where would I add config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = true

Comment: @StephenScottMoore You would add that to `config/application.rb`. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 6.1, `form_with` implement `local: true` by default.
So you need to add `local: false` to submit form using an XHR (Ajax) request:

```rb
form_with(model: [@post, @element], local: false)
```